# Show the *Completions* buffer automatically when starting completing-read

Tags: completion

I want to do a completing read with the `*Completions*` buffer already shown (because I'm providing initial input that I already know is an ambiguous prefix). How can I do it?

I don't see an option for this in `completing-read`. I want a method that works in both Emacs 23 (where `completing-read` is defined in C) and in Emacs 24 (where `completing-read` relays to the function indicated by the variable `completing-read-function`, so I suppose I could just change that) — of course a solution based on `(if (boundp 'completing-read-function))` is fine.

Although my immediate use case is with a known ambiguous initial input, something that works regardless of that would be nice. Also, if the user has overridden the default read mechanism (e.g. by redefining `completing-read` to invoke `ido-completing-read` or `anything-completing-read` or by turning on Icicles or Helm), I'd like my code to achieve the same effect, i.e. start the completion mechanism with the list of completions already shown.

Answer (score 7):

Last time I needed this, I used something like:

```
(minibuffer-with-setup-hook
    #'minibuffer-completion-help
  (completing-read ...))
```

Answer (score 1):

My quick-and-dirty solution (tested with Emacs 23 but it should work with any version) was to pretend that the user had pressed <kbd>Tab</kbd> — since I already know that the input is ambiguous, this displays the `*Completions*` buffer. It works well enough in practice, but it's a very dirty hack since it assumes that the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key is bound to performing completion, and it only works if the initial input is an ambiguous prefix.

```
(setq unread-command-events (cons 'tab unread-command-events))
(completing-read message completions nil nil known-ambiguous-prefix history-variable)
```

Answer (score 1):

If [**Icicles**](http://www.emacswiki.org/Icicles) counts for you as part of "etc." in your "Solutions that work with... etc.", then you need only set or bind variable **`icicle-show-Completions-initially-flag`** to non-`nil`.

If it does not, try calling `display-completion-list` (from buffer `*Completions*`) when you want `*Completions*` to be displayed. If you want all completions for your `known-ambiguous` input to be displayed, then use `all-completions` to calculate the list of completions, and pass that list to `display-completion-list`.

---

Update:

Based on your comments, Stefan's answer works with or without **Icicles** (e.g., with *Icicle* mode on or off):

```el
(defun foo ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((comps  (all-completions known-ambiguous-prefix completions)))
    (minibuffer-with-setup-hook
      #'minibuffer-completion-help
      (completing-read "Choose: " comps))))
```

But with **Icicles** you can get the same behavior more simply:

```el
(defun foo ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((comps  (all-completions known-ambiguous-prefix completions))
        (icicle-show-Completions-initially-flag  t))
    (completing-read "Choose: " comps)))
```

Comment: By “solutions that work with…”, I meant solutions that work if the user has replaced the basic completion machinery by a more powerful package, not solutions that *require* an extra package — obviously I don't prefer to require an extra package.

Comment: 1. I don't know what you mean by "*the user has replaced the basic completion machinery by a more powerful package*" - especially what that might mean *without such a package being required*. But whatever... 2. Did you try `all-completions` and `display-completion-list`? In what way does that not do what you want? 3. So far, your question remains not very clear, at least to me.

Comment: 1. Whether to use Icicles/Helm/… is a user choice. I want my code to be compatible with any choice the user has made. For example, if the user has `(defalias 'completing-read 'ido-completing-read)`, I want my code to work reasonably. 2. `all-completions` and `display-completion-list` are just some of the building bricks: I'd need to write (copy?) more code to create and display the completions buffer. 3. I've edited the bit that bothers you in my question. I've also posted an answer which does what I want in `emacs -q` but isn't robust to user customizations.

Comment: In that case, then with or without **Icicles**, the code that Stefan suggested does just what you want.  With **Icicles**, it is fine as suggested, but it is not needed - all you need is to bind `icicle-show-completions-initially-flag` around your call to `completing-read`. The behavior in both cases is the same.

Answer (score 0):

If you activave helm-mode: `(helm-mode 1)`and whenever `completing-read` happens, it shows all candidates in a Helm buffer for interactive selecting. With `helm-mode` on, no `*Completions*` buffer will show up because it is replaced by Helm buffer. It works with prefix too. For example, you can try this with `helm-mode` activated:

```
(completing-read "test: " '("aaa" "bbb" "abc" "abbbb") nil t "ab")
```

A Helm buffer appears and with only two candidates with "ab" prefix: "aabc" and "abbbb".